# WinRM Negotiate get 200 instead of 401

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, winrm

I am working on a Ruby on Rails application which uses the WinRM library to access a remote Windows server. The transport supplied is :negotiate which will negotiate the authentication with the remote server.

The issue is the WinRM library expects a 401 HTTP status code so that it can send more data for authentication. However, a 200 HTTP status code is returned and the negotiate fails.

The backtrace is :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
    from /home/cobalt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/winrm-1.7.3/lib/winrm/http/transport.rb:226:in `init_auth'
    from /home/cobalt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/winrm-1.7.3/lib/winrm/http/transport.rb:166:in `send_request'
    from /home/cobalt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/winrm-1.7.3/lib/winrm/winrm_service.rb:489:in `send_message'
    from /home/cobalt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/winrm-1.7.3/lib/winrm/winrm_service.rb:390:in `run_wql'
    from /home/cobalt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/winrm-1.7.3/lib/winrm/command_executor.rb:186:in `os_version'
    from /home/cobalt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/winrm-1.7.3/lib/winrm/command_executor.rb:145:in `code_page'
    from /home/cobalt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/winrm-1.7.3/lib/winrm/command_executor.rb:72:in `block in open'
    from /home/cobalt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/winrm-1.7.3/lib/winrm/command_executor.rb:218:in `retryable'
    from /home/cobalt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/winrm-1.7.3/lib/winrm/command_executor.rb:71:in `open'
    from (irb):20
    from /home/cobalt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /home/cobalt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/cobalt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /home/cobalt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/cobalt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'2.2.2 :021 >
```

The TCP Dump shows the below package exchanges

```
 tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
12:04:08.372376 IP d8b5d56cba65.53166 > pokcpeusap02.corp.absc.local.wsman: Flags [S], seq 2899844066, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1316187676 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
        0x0000:  4500 003c 75fe 4000 4006 d486 0400 0005  E..<u.@.@.......
        0x0010:  0acd e165 cfae 1761 acd8 1be2 0000 0000  ...e...a........
        0x0020:  a002 7210 f065 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ..r..e..........
        0x0030:  4e73 6e1c 0000 0000 0103 0307            Nsn.........
12:04:08.421019 IP pokcpeusap02.corp.absc.local.wsman > d8b5d56cba65.53166: Flags [S.], seq 3702856093, ack 2899844067, win 8192, options [mss 1351,nop,wscale 8,sackOK,TS val 79780711 ecr 1316187676],
 length 0
        0x0000:  4500 003c 7f04 4000 7d06 8e80 0acd e165  E..<..@.}......e
        0x0010:  0400 0005 1761 cfae dcb5 199d acd8 1be3  .....a..........
        0x0020:  a012 2000 754e 0000 0204 0547 0103 0308  ....uN.....G....
        0x0030:  0402 080a 04c1 5b67 4e73 6e1c            ......[gNsn.
12:04:08.421047 IP d8b5d56cba65.53166 > pokcpeusap02.corp.absc.local.wsman: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1316187725 ecr 79780711], length 0
        0x0000:  4500 0034 75ff 4000 4006 d48d 0400 0005  E..4u.@.@.......
        0x0010:  0acd e165 cfae 1761 acd8 1be3 dcb5 199e  ...e...a........
        0x0020:  8010 00e5 f05d 0000 0101 080a 4e73 6e4d  .....]......NsnM
        0x0030:  04c1 5b67                                ..[g
12:04:08.421368 IP d8b5d56cba65.53166 > pokcpeusap02.corp.absc.local.wsman: Flags [P.], seq 1:340, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1316187725 ecr 79780711], length 339
        0x0000:  4500 0187 7600 4000 4006 d339 0400 0005  E...v.@.@..9....
        0x0010:  0acd e165 cfae 1761 acd8 1be3 dcb5 199e  ...e...a........
        0x0020:  8018 00e5 f1b0 0000 0101 080a 4e73 6e4d  ............NsnM
        0x0030:  04c1 5b67 504f 5354 202f 7773 6d61 6e20  ..[gPOST./wsman.
        0x0040:  4854 5450 2f31 2e31 0d0a 4175 7468 6f72  HTTP/1.1..Author
        0x0050:  697a 6174 696f 6e3a 204e 6567 6f74 6961  ization:.Negotia
        0x0060:  7465 2054 6c52 4d54 564e 5455 4141 4241  te.TlRMTVNTUAABA
        0x0070:  4141 414e 3449 4934 4151 4142 4141 6741  AAAN4II4AQABAAgA
        0x0080:  4141 4141 4141 4141 4351 4141 4142 4462  AAAAAAAACQAAABDb
        0x0090:  334a 775a 4468 694e 5751 314e 6d4e 6959  3JwZDhiNWQ1NmNiY
        0x00a0:  5459 310d 0a43 6f6e 7465 6e74 2d54 7970  TY1..Content-Typ
        0x00b0:  653a 2061 7070 6c69 6361 7469 6f6e 2f73  e:.application/s
        0x00c0:  6f61 702b 786d 6c3b 6368 6172 7365 743d  oap+xml;charset=
        0x00d0:  5554 462d 380d 0a55 7365 722d 4167 656e  UTF-8..User-Agen
        0x00e0:  743a 2052 7562 7920 5769 6e52 4d20 436c  t:.Ruby.WinRM.Cl
        0x00f0:  6965 6e74 2028 322e 372e 312c 2072 7562  ient.(2.7.1,.rub
        0x0100:  7920 322e 322e 3220 2832 3031 352d 3034  y.2.2.2.(2015-04
        0x0110:  2d31 3329 290d 0a41 6363 6570 743a 202a  -13))..Accept:.*
        0x0120:  2f2a 0d0a 4461 7465 3a20 5475 652c 2030  /*..Date:.Tue,.0
        0x0130:  3720 4d61 7220 3230 3137 2031 323a 3034  7.Mar.2017.12:04
        0x0140:  3a30 3820 474d 540d 0a43 6f6e 7465 6e74  :08.GMT..Content
        0x0150:  2d4c 656e 6774 683a 2030 0d0a 486f 7374  -Length:.0..Host
        0x0160:  3a20 706f 6b63 7065 7573 6170 3032 2e63  :.pokcpeusap02.c
        0x0170:  6f72 702e 6162 7363 2e6c 6f63 616c 3a35  orp.absc.local:5
        0x0180:  3938 350d 0a0d 0a                        985....
12:04:08.516497 IP pokcpeusap02.corp.absc.local.wsman > d8b5d56cba65.53166: Flags [P.], seq 1:39, ack 340, win 256, options [nop,nop,TS val 79780721 ecr 1316187725], length 38
        0x0000:  4500 005a 7f05 4000 7d06 8e61 0acd e165  E..Z..@.}..a...e
        0x0010:  0400 0005 1761 cfae dcb5 199e acd8 1d36  .....a.........6
        0x0020:  8018 0100 11f4 0000 0101 080a 04c1 5b71  ..............[q
        0x0030:  4e73 6e4d 4854 5450 2f31 2e31 2032 3030  NsnMHTTP/1.1.200
        0x0040:  204f 4b0d 0a43 6f6e 7465 6e74 2d4c 656e  .OK..Content-Len
        0x0050:  6774 683a 2030 0d0a 0d0a                 gth:.0....
12:04:08.516541 IP d8b5d56cba65.53166 > pokcpeusap02.corp.absc.local.wsman: Flags [.], ack 39, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1316187821 ecr 79780721], length 0
        0x0000:  4500 0034 7601 4000 4006 d48b 0400 0005  E..4v.@.@.......
        0x0010:  0acd e165 cfae 1761 acd8 1d36 dcb5 19c4  ...e...a...6....
        0x0020:  8010 00e5 f05d 0000 0101 080a 4e73 6ead  .....]......Nsn.
        0x0030:  04c1 5b71                                ..[q
```

What would be the issue? Why I don't get a 401 HTTP status code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havae managed to found the root cause of the issue. It turns out there is another service  instead of WinRM srevice is listening to port 5985. Hence when a request is sent to that port, that service responded with a respone requiring Basic Authentication and the status code 200. The issue is fixed after starting WinRM service and make it listen at port 5985.

The detailed analysis can be found at [Ruby WinRM undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass](http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1488959186-Ruby-WinRM-undefined-method-%60split-for-nil%3ANilClass). It's really a good lesson to learn. Sometimes the issue is very simple and stupid, but to find out the issue would take much effort.